# Dropdown doesn't disappear on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, touch, mouseenter

I have a simple dropdown button which shows content when user clicks or taps (on touch screens) the button. It works great but on some mobile devices (especially iPad and devices with Windows Mobile), the dropdown doesn't disappear when user touch the screen outside the dropdown.

Here's HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-toggle">Click Me</div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">Example contnt of the dropdown</div>
</div>
```

Here's JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.dropdown', function() {

    $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').show();

}).on('mouseleave', '.dropdown', function() {

    $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').hide();

});
```

- Why it doesn't work on these devices?
- What other events I should use?
- And most important: how to make the dropdown disappear properly on all devices? Cross-browser and cross-device solution would be great.

Comment: there isn't `mouse` events (apart from `click`, also, `click` event slow than `touch` events) on mobile devices( android, ios ). I suggest that  use `hammer.js` for cross-platform

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `touchstart` event to the following

```
$(document).on('mouseenter touchstart', '.dropdown', function() {
```

And likewise, the `touchend` event on the mouseout

```
}).on('mouseleave touchend', '.dropdown', function() {
```

Comment: Is it cross-browser solution?

Comment: @zitix, yes this should be compatible with the majority of browsers.